# generating custom colorbar: match data with color scheme

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3D bar chart, generated from 3D discrete-dataset(`x,y,z`).
Used this code to plot on canvas:

```
bar_chart_3d =fx.bar3d(x, y, z, dx, dy, dz, color=cmap.to_rgba(dz), alpha=0.4,linewidth=0.5)
```

But, I'm not being able to attach the `colormap` on the canvas based on which `dz` value is plotted.
Tried using:

```
#Adding a color-bar...
fig.colorbar(cmap.to_rgba(dz), shrink=0.6, aspect=8)
```

But this is invoking `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bar3d [docs](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.bar3d), the color applied is to each face,

> color can be:
>
> An array of colors of length N bars, to color each bar independently.

I guess as this is just a facecolor, it is not assumed to convey information and the bar3d does not return anything.
Things like contour return a `ScalarMappable` which can be used to specify the colorbar. It looks like your cmap (which I assume is a `cm.ScalarMappable`?) doesn't contain norm and autoscale required for colorbar.

As a work around you can draw the colorbar yourself between certain limits as in this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html)

```
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.10, 0.9, 0.1])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=dz.min(), vmax=dz.max())
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap=mpl.cm.cool,
                               norm=norm,
                               orientation='horizontal')
```

where you minimum and maximum for `dz` specify a range which is consistent with your data.

EDIT: added a minimum working example where you specify a colormap, use it to get bar colors and add this colormap to the bottom.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x, y = np.random.rand(2, 100) * 4
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4)

elements = (len(xedges) - 1) * (len(yedges) - 1)
xpos, ypos = np.meshgrid(xedges[:-1]+0.25, yedges[:-1]+0.25)

xpos = xpos.flatten()
ypos = ypos.flatten()
zpos = np.zeros(elements)
dx = 0.5 * np.ones_like(zpos)
dy = dx.copy()
dz = hist.flatten()

#Define colormap and get values for barcolors from it
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=dz.min(), vmax=dz.max())
barcolors = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm, cmap)

#Plot bar3d
ax.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color=barcolors.to_rgba(dz),alpha=0.4,linewidth=0.5, zsort='average')

#Add colorbar
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.10, 0.9, 0.1])
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax1, cmap=cmap,
                                   norm=norm,
                                   orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

Which gives,
[image]

Comment: I used `color=cmap.to_rgba(dz)` while plotting the `bar-chart`, so as per your example when I try to put `cmap=cmap.to_rgba` the code also crashes. Any idea how can I be able to put `rgba` to `cmap`.

Comment: I've added a minimum example of how you could do this, the idea is you choose a `cmap`, get the bar colors from it and then plot the `colorbar` for the entire range (consistent with the range of `dz` bar values) at the bottom.